# Death as a parallel or serial process

Tags: science-fiction, universe, death, life

In this world, conscience takes a particular amount of -a special kind of - energy to be hosted by a functional brain.

If prior and post life exists due to parallel universes, **would you bet life and death "travel" across this universes in a parallel process (many at a time) or a serial process (one at a time)?**

Either way, there must be a limit, I'm working on the implications of when this limit is reached.

Comment: Not completely sure what you are asking, but this brings to mind the image of Saint Peter standing outside the gates of Heaven with his naughty list. The dead are queued up as far as the eye can see. The recently deceased from a parallel universe join the queue. Saint Peter palms face.

Comment: Parallel? Universe generally works in parallel, so unless you have some specific constraint in mind I'd bet on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For convenience I'll refer to what is being transported as the essence - feel free to assign your own meaning to that.

I think you are asking about the channel or medium by which the essence travels to the <strike>parallel</strike> other universe. Is this process serialized (only one essence at a time) or parallel (many essences at a time).

---

From your wording, you are suggesting that the process is serial. Because what you call parallel described as "many at a time" is not concurrent. A process can be parallel but not concurrent if while executing it doesn’t allow another process to start. When you say "many at a time", I understand that you transport essences in batch. In other words, the instances of the process are not independent... once a batch is full, it is sent, and any incoming essences must wait until that process is done to start a new batch.

... Yet, I suspect that that isn't what you mean ...

---

So, assuming that transporting an essence is a transaction*, we have:

Serial (not parallel and not concurrent): one essence is transported at a time.

Parallel (parallel and not concurrent): a batch of essences is transported at a time.

Concurrent (parallel and concurrent): each essence is transported independently.

*: Being it a transaction means that either you transport it or not, there si no "it is stuck in between" and no "it only transported half of it".

---

What is the nature of this process?

Is this a process carried by some agent or entity that goes by collecting the essences and sending them to their destination? if so, it depends on that agent or entity how things work.

On the other hand, if this is a natural process, then it is expected that it follows the principles of universality - that is: "all laws of nature must work the same way everywhere" - and locality - that is: "an object is only directly influenced by its immediate surroundings".

The above means that you cannot enforce a universal lock that prevents the execution of new instances of the process. In other words, if a process is executing in some place it cannot prevent another process to start on the other side of the universe - because that would require the transmission of information across the universe instantaneously* - in abstract: multiple simultaneous executions of the process must be possible.

So, we conclude that the process must be concurrent. Many essences can be transported simultaneously, independently of each other.

*: If you try to imagine such process it would require to send a signal when it starts. This signal then travels across the universe and causes any other process that may start to wait until the first one completes. The problem is that that signal has to travel at some speed; therefore another process may start before receiving the signal. So, we can conclude that a natural process cannot happen in only one place at a time. Instead it must be possible for it to happen in multiple places simultaneously... unless the universe of your fictional work allows for natural instantaneous communication.

Answer (score 2):

Of course! This is reincarnation using parallel universes as the places where the person lived both before and after. So the person 'passes' to another universe either one at a time or many at once. This is nifty update of karma.

The main problem to be considered is whether the number of parallel universes is finite or unbounded as in an infinite number of parallel universes.

If the parallel universes are part of a multiverse their number could be infinite. If this is so, considering the implications of running out of parallel universes to be incarnated in is a moot point. Whatever limits exist would arise from something other than running out of universes.

If the number of parallel universes is finite, then the limits can be reached quicker. If the person is reincarnated multiple times in parallel, then any limit will be attained reasonably soon (where reasonably soon may be what geologists and astronomers call an extremely long time).

If the person is migrating from one parallel universe after another, then provided the total number of parallel universes isn't too excessive a limit will be eventually reached.

It does seem that what you are calling a 'conscience' which is hosted by functioning brains is what theological fuddy-duddies in days of yore called a 'soul'. However, this proposal for reincarnation involves a goodly number of parallel universes with functioning brains living in them. This seems to be a reasonably consistent model for a reincarnation friendly cosmos.